# Does cutting off the taylor expansion of e^x always give an irreducible polynomial?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

I am talking of the polynomials:
$P_n(x)$ = $1+x..+x^n/n!$

I've tested this for the first 10 values and it seems so. I know this might be random but I've got a hunch that there's something deeper here.

For prime $n$ this follows from Eisenstein's principle, but I don't have much progress on other values.

Comment: @JohnMachacek Thanks! I couldn't find it when looking :(

Comment: And I also posted this on MO instead of ME, sorry!